# Mule 3.2.1 CE: Extract a value from an input XML and remember it for later usage

Tags: logging, xpath, mule

I'm trying to extract a value from an incoming SOAP request using xpath, but for one reason or another Mule wont recognize it as xml. In the code-sample here I'm just trying to log the information, and I suspect Mule just transforms the Mule message to a string, which results in something like "[B4FEfea"; the standard output of toString(). And the xpath expression fails on that one.

The flow itself works fine and from SOAP-UI I can send a request and a response comes back without the logger component, but inside the response I also want to add a part of the input and that fails.

Here's the flow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:core="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="CE-3.2.1" xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd ">
    <mulexml:namespace-manager includeConfigNamespaces="false">  
        <mulexml:namespace prefix="soapenv" uri="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>  
        <mulexml:namespace prefix="mob" uri="http://mobistar.be/spellchecker/"/> 
    </mulexml:namespace-manager>

    <flow name="spellcheckerFlow2" doc:name="spellcheckerFlow2" processingStrategy="synchronous">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="spellcheck" contentType="text/xml" doc:name="SOAP Spell check"/>
        <logger message="#[xpath://mob:Text]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <mulexml:xslt-transformer maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5" xsl-file="E:\Projects\Mobistar\Mule\spellchecker\src\main\resources\Request2GoogleAPI.xslt" doc:name="XSLT"/>
        <response>
            <mulexml:xslt-transformer maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5" xsl-file="E:\Projects\Mobistar\Mule\spellchecker\src\main\resources\GoogleAPI2Response.xslt" doc:name="XSLT"/>
        </response>
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="www.google.com" port="80" path="tbproxy/spell?lang=en" contentType="text/xml" doc:name="Google API"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

The request I'm sending is this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:spel="http://mobistar.be/spellchecker/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <spel:CheckSpellingRequest>
         <spel:Text>Please test this blabla</spel:Text>
      </spel:CheckSpellingRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: I just noticed that the incoming message is of type org.apache.commons.httpclient.ContentLengthInputStream. How come the Echo and xslt transformer action have no problem with this, but the logger can't deal with it?

Comment: I was running your config and noticed the same. After checking the code, I can tell you that you either need to transform the inbound content to a String or to a DOM prior to use an Xpath expression. Then it works.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the XPath is incorrect, you should try

/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/spel:CheckSpellingRequest/spel:Text

If you want to store a value to use it latter you can use message properties:

To store a property:

```
<message-properties-transformer scope="session">    
<add-message-property key="incomingText"
    value="#[xpath://soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/spel:CheckSpellingRequest/spel:Text]" />
</message-properties-transformer>
```

To read a property:

```
<logger message="#[header:session: incomingText]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```